# Execute C# exe embeddded as a resource in a C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, linker

I have a Windows application built in C++ (`c++App.exe`), and a .NET Windows application built in C# (`c#App.exe`).

I'm embedding the `c#App.exe` as a resource into `c++App.exe`.

When I run `c++App.exe`, I perform some checks, and if they all pass, I'd like to execute the `c#App.exe` embedded as resource.

What I've tried so far:

- Extract the `csharpApp.exe` to a temporary file, and execute it via [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)
- Host the [.NET CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/9x0wh2z3(v=vs.90)) in my C++ app, and load the C# assembly into an AppDomain, and call the `Program.Main` function via Reflection

---

Is there any other alternative to what I've tried? What I would like is to be able to call the `c#App.exe` directly from `c++App.exe`, without having to write to disk, and without having all the complications of loading the .NET Common Language Runtime into my C++ app.

Is there something like `CreateProcessFromBytes` where I can pass a reference to my `c#App.exe` embedded resource, and its entry point gets called like a normal executable (and the entry point is then in charge of loading the CLR, etc...)?

- I know I cannot use ILMerge, because the it's C++
- I don't want to use any setup-kind of app such as MSI / NSIS, WiX, etc. I would like to do everything programatically myself
- I don't want to use any self-extracting packer like 7-zip, or WinZip, etc. I would like to do everything programatically myself

Comment: Is there any good reason to host your own .net CLR in your app? Isn't every modern windows OS ship with .net framework pre installed? Does your `c++app.exe` do something useful beside hosting .net CLR? Have you heard about [.net Native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/)?

Comment: I *do not* want to host the .NET CLR in my app... That's the point. I cannot use .NET Native because my app needs to run on Windows 7 and onwards...